# Did i set my file pointer wrong?

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
void CharReadWrite(FILE *fin);
FILE *fptr2;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   

    char filename[]="ReadMe.txt";
    if (fopen_s( &fptr2, filename, "r" ) != 0 )
      printf( "File stream %s was not opened\n", filename );
    else
      printf( "The file %s was opened\n", filename );
    CharReadWrite(fptr2);
    fclose(fptr2);
    return 0;
    }
void CharReadWrite(FILE *fin){
    int c;
    while ((c=fgetc(fin)) !=EOF) {
        putchar(c);}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What error do you get?

Comment: (c=fgetc(fin) !=EOF) has a parenthesis misplaced. Should be (c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're opening ReadMe.txt for writing:

```
fopen_s( &fptr2, filename, "w" )
```

but then passing it to `CharReadWrite`:

```
CharReadWrite(fptr2);
```

which tries to read from it:

```
c=fgetc(fin)
```

Did you mean to open it for reading, by passing `"r"` to `fopen_s`?

You also carry on and call `CharReadWrite` if opening ReadMe.txt fails.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are attempting to read from (and then close) `fptr2` even if you failed to open it.

Try:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
void CharReadWrite(FILE *fin);
FILE *fptr2;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   

    char filename[]="ReadMe.txt";
    if (fopen_s( &fptr2, filename, "w" ) != 0 )
    {
      printf( "File stream %s was not opened\n", filename );
    }
    else
    {
      printf( "The file %s was opened\n", filename );
      CharReadWrite(fptr2);
      fclose(fptr2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

if (fopen_s( &fptr2, filename, "w" ) != 0 )

When you pass the 'w' flag,  ["Create an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists its content is erased and the file is treated as a new empty file."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)

Instead, use the "r+" flag.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening file for writing and trying to read from it (fgetc) ...